# Quickbooks Transaction Detail by Account Report using Quickbooks API

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to access the information that is provided by Transaction Detail by Account report from the quickbooks UI using the Quickbooks API. I can see the TransactionList resource which is the equivalent report Transaction List by Date.

I am not sure how I can access the information from quickbooks API to get the Transaction Detail by Account report information and add the filter for Distribution Account.

I would really appreciate help on this.

Thank you

I have spent a few hours searching for any similar solutions but could not find any. I also could not find Quickbooks community forums. I am hoping somebody would have solved this problem and can give me some insights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.